# edit existing excel on web page using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

Does anyone have an idea to create the dynamic form with uploaded excel file.

We need to facilitate users to add data in the pre-uploaded file. Can anyone help with this? We are doing in this way:

```
$objPHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'HTML');
$objPHPExcelWriter->save('php://output');
```

But this above code only displays structure of excel on the web still we're unable to edit it.

Comment: You'll probably have to go over the data line by line and create input fields.

Comment: Yu'll need to write all the front-end editing code yourself, because PHPExcel isn't a straight PHP substitute for MS Excel itself, simply a library that allows you to read and write spreadsheet data

Answer (score 0):

you will need 2 pear packages

PHP-ExcelReader package
Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package
What you need to do is read first the excel file use PHP-ExcelReader package It reads the binary format of XLS files directly and can return values and formats from any cell. http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

read the excel file

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls");
```

show the data of the file

```
$data->dump($row_numbers=false,$col_letters=false,$sheet=0,$table_class='excel')
```

Once you have stored the data in a variable save the data in another file this time you will use the The Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package https://github.com/pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

```
<?php
   require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';
   $workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer('test.xls');
   $worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('My first worksheet');
   if (PEAR::isError($worksheet)) {
     die($worksheet->getMessage());
   }
   $workbook->close();
?>
```

Comment: excel reader unable to read data....we want to implement formula as well. Can you solve this with PHPExcel... thanks in advance